# ruby hash searching for two criterias

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
grades = [
  {:student=>"James", :age=>19, :score=>85},
  {:student=>"Kate", :age=>19, :score=>92},
  {:student=>"Sara", :age=>20, :score=>74},
  {:student=>"Riley", :age=>20, :score=>85},
  {:student=>"patrick", :age=>20, :score=>96},
  {:student=>"luke", :age=>21, :score=>88},
  {:student=>"susie", :age=>21, :score=>90}
]
```

I am trying to get the student with the highest score that is the age 20 but only can sort the highest by all the students. Does any one know how to limit the max_by to only students that are 20 from the above hash ?

Answer (score 4):

1. filter for people with age 20
2. find the maximum score

   ```
   grades.select { |person| person[:age] == 20 }.max_by { |person| person[:score] }
   ```

Comment: You misread the question as I did. The OP wants the student's name.

Comment: The answer returns the grade hash from which you can simply extract the student though.

Answer (score 1):

My objective is to make a single pass through the hashes.

Initially I posted the following, but it was incorrect because it returns the name of a student who is not 20 if there are no students of age 20.

```
grades.max { |h| h[:age] == 20 ? h[:score] :
  -Float::INFINITY }[:student]
```

Here is my revised answer:

```
def best20(grades)
  student = nil
  highest = -Float::INFINITY
  grades.each do |h|
    if h[:age] == 20 && h[:score] > highest
      highest = h[:score]
      student = h[:student]
    end
  end
  student
end

best20 grades
  #=> "patrick"

best20 [{:student=>"James", :age=>19, :score=>85}]
  #=> nil
```

Comment: Not the downvoter, sorry. Would max work in a case like `grades.max { |person| person[:age] == 20 ? 1 : 0 }`?

Comment: @Sabastian, you are right, `max` is sufficient, but `1 : 0` won't work because we only the the 20-year old student with the highest score.

Answer (score 0):

Just as idea.

Suppose we have several 20-year-old students with the same maximum score.

In this case variants of Cary and Ursus return only first person.

Therefore, such a thought occurred to me:

```
grades = [
  {:student=>"James", :age=>19, :score=>85},
  {:student=>"Kate", :age=>19, :score=>92},
  {:student=>"Sara", :age=>20, :score=>74},
  {:student=>"Riley", :age=>20, :score=>85},
  {:student=>"Patrick", :age=>20, :score=>96},
  {:student=>"Vladimir", :age=>20, :score=>96},
  {:student=>"Luke", :age=>21, :score=>88},
  {:student=>"Susie", :age=>21, :score=>90}
]

def best20(grades)
  students20 = grades.select { |r| r[:age] == 20 }
  return nil if students20.empty?
  max_score20 = students20.max_by { |r| r[:score] }[:score]
  students20.select { |r| r[:score] == max_score20 }.map { |r| r[:student] }
end

best20 grades
# => ["Patrick", "Vladimir"]

best20 [{:student=>"James", :age=>19, :score=>85}]
# => nil
```

Do not judge strictly, this is just an idea.